# How to make the horizontal navigation in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

Using Zend, I want to create a navigation like:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="/coupon/index/all"></a>    
    </li>   
    <li>
        <a href="/coupon/index/most-popuplar">Most Popular</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/coupon/index/most-recent">Most Recent</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/coupon/index/ending-soon">Ending Soon</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### But when I used Zend Navigation with config like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
    <nav>
        <label>All</label>
        <module>coupon</module>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>all</action>
        <pages>
            <popuplar>
                <label>Most Popular</label>
                <module>coupon</module>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>most-popuplar</action>
            </popuplar>
            <recent>
                <label>Most Recent</label>
                <module>coupon</module>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>most-recent</action>
            </recent>
            <ending>
                <label>Ending Soon</label>
                <module>coupon</module>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>ending-soon</action>
            </ending>
        </pages>
    </nav>
</configdata>
```

### The result is always:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="/coupon/index/all"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/coupon/index/most-popuplar">Most Popular</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/coupon/index/most-recent">Most Recent</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/coupon/index/ending-soon">Ending Soon</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> **So**, I know that I am wrong with my config, but I don't know how to make it becomes correct. Could you please help me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to fix this is to move your `allAction` into the pages node. And really that's the way it *should* be structured, because you're not using an `indexAction`. You've put your `allAction` where the `indexAction` should be.

If you don't have an `indexAction`, you should just ignore it in your XML navigation config, as well. That will at least get you closer to what you're looking for.

**Or**, if you're looking to use this config for general purpose, you should add the `indexAction` where you have the `allAction` right now, and then do something like this in your layout or other view (or wherever):

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setMinDepth(1); ?>
```

Then in your css file:

```
.navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the pages out of the `<pages>` tag and enclose the "all" action page in its own tag.

If you use the navigation config only for the navigation object you are more or less free to structure that in any way you like.